# MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE is deprecated?

Tags: android

```
File f = new File(MainActivity.appContext.getFilesDir(), "Captured.jpg");
                f.delete();
                //Create new file
                FileOutputStream fos = MainActivity.appContext.openFileOutput("Captured.jpg", Context
                        .MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);
                //FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);

                fos.close();
                //Get reference to the file
                filezz = new File(MainActivity.appContext.getFilesDir(), "Captured.jpg");
```

as MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE is deprecated and i don't want to go with that code so

can i get the replcement of above code ?

Answer (score 1):

Replace `Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE` with `0` or `Context.MODE_PRIVATE`.

Comment: This answer makes no sense.
So Context.MODE_PRIVATE means 2 things now, private and public?

Comment: @AriesConnolly: No. `MODE_PRIVATE` is private. There is no world-readable or world-writeable options anymore. The OP was asking what to use to replace `ontext.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE` with a non-deprecated option, and the only such option is `Context.MODE_PRIVATE`.

Comment: But it's not a replacement, it's like replacing a hippo with a cat

Comment: @AriesConnolly: For a variable of type `Animal`, that would be a valid substitution. In the context of the OP's question, the code in question was probably copied-and-pasted from some ancient security-ignorant blog post. And so, six years ago, I steered the OP towards the secure and minimally-invasive alternative. Since there isn't much in the way of world-readable options today (and effectively no world-writeable options), there isn't really a straight-up replacement for the OP's code.

Comment: And yet I have a number of picture editing apps on my phone. Each of them can update an image, so it's not private to any one of these apps. What are they using?

Comment: @AriesConnolly: Presumably they are using `MediaStore`.

Comment: @AriesConnolly: More specifically, if they are presenting you with a picture gallery to choose from, they are using `MediaStore`. If, OTOH, they give you a platform-supplied "file open"-style UI to choose the photo, then they are using the Storage Access Framework (`ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` / `ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocument`).

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing this from bitmap then use below code

```
Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bytes);

                File destination = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Captured.jpg");
                FileOutputStream fo;

                try {
                    destination.createNewFile();
                    fo = new FileOutputStream(destination);
                    fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
                    fo.close();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```